# Lots of IIS requests get stuck on Session Module Name and State ReleaseRequestState on my .Net Framework API

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, iis, request, freeze

We have a .net framework 4.6.1 API hosted on IIS on a Windows Server (I do not have much detail on system infrastructure, though) I believe there are 6 machines on AWS  with 3.00 GB processors and the memory nevere goes over 30-40%. There's a load balancer which round robin to each instance.

The issue is that when we receive a lot of traffic, more than 200k request at the same time, the load balancer from aws shut down the machines. Later they recover.

The state and module are different from the image (ReleaseRequestState and Session). It's an API, not a web, so we don't understand the session state.

[image: Screenshot similar to what happen]

We have added logs and we have observed the request that may cause the issue. This request call an external API that can handle all the traffic it receive.

We have tried a couple of improvements:

- Pass the method to async await paradigm from entering the controller
- Increase the number of defaultconnectionlimit on servicepointmanager

It seems that from time to time the server respond better but sometimes when the peak of traffic the machines are out again.

Comment: You have tried the most efficient approaches but the ultimate blocker is the external API and you cannot really make it quicker.